# Calling a PHP file every 3 seconds

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I want to call from html file(using jQuery) to php file every 3 seconds.

Where i wrong in the following call:

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
       <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery('document').ready(function() {
        setInterval(function() {
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: "index.php",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "HTML",
                success: function(data) {
                    document.getElementById("mainImage").src = data;
                    },
                });
        }, 3000);
    });
</script>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
         <img id="mainImage">
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you including jQuery elsewhere?

Comment: and a total lack of any timer-related code as well...

Comment: Also, this will only make the call once.

Comment: @marc B see my edit, i upload wrong code.

Comment: @mikeChristensen see my edit, i upload wrong code

Comment: You need a `<script>` tag..

Comment: so **HOW** is this not working for you, now that you've shown the real code? "not working" doesn't help us AT ALL.

Comment: sorry for the discomfort guys. now you can see the right code.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see anything in your code that is including the jQuery library. You need to do that. Also, I do not see anything that is set to call the function every 3 seconds.

After adding the call to load the jQuery lib,

wrap your function in this:

```
setInterval(function() {
jQuery.ajax({            
            url: "index.php", 
        type: "POST",          
        dataType: "HTML", 
            success: function( data ) { 
        jQuery('body').append(data);
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, data ) {        
        alert ('Ajax request Failed.');    
        }
        }); 
  }, 3000); //3 seconds
```

Answer (score 1):

You don’t seem to have `<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>` tags around your in place and your HTML structure seems off. And hey, you are not even loading `jQuery` so that was added too. Also note I also changed 2000 (which is 2 seconds) to 3000 (which is 3 seconds) since that is the title of this question. So here is the reworked sample:

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
      jQuery('document').ready(function() {
        setInterval(function() {
          jQuery.ajax({
            url: "index.php",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "HTML",
            success: function(data) {
                document.getElementById("mainImage").src = data;
                },
            });
        }, 3000);
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
         <img id="mainImage">
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, make sure jQuery is actually included on your page. I've also altered your code to be a little more reliable, as it will only call the script again 3 seconds after the first call has successfully executed:

```
<script>
jQuery('document').ready(function() {
    updateSrc();
});

function updateSrc() {
  jQuery.ajax({
      url: "index.php",
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "HTML",
      success: function(data) {
        document.getElementById("mainImage").src = data;
        // once the ajax call is returned, call the function again after 3 seconds
        setTimeout(updateSrc(), 3000);
      },
  });
}
</script>
```